# Question about ellipsoid method

Tags: optimization

I have some technical question concerning the ellipsoid method Referring to the paper :

http://paswkshop.comm.utoronto.ca/~weiyu/01658226.pdf

It is mentioned in p.1317 at the last line in the left column that "When the subgradient of the dual objective function has a bounded norm [26], the ellipsoid update is guaranteed to converge"

Now, the question is what if the subgradient doesn't have a bounded norm ? Can convergence to the optimal multiplier value still take place ? In my problem, there is no upper bound on the multiplier value like what the authors did in the attached paper in equation (23).